# F# - Breaking a List into Concatenated Strings by an Interval

Tags: .net, f#, list, concatenation, fold

I have a list of email addresses, and I need to send an email notification to each address. I'd like to do this in blocks of 25 addresses at a time. Is there any quick way in a functional language like F# to "fold" (concatenate) 25 emails addresses together... each separated by a semicolon. I know there is the String.Split method in .NET, but I need to concat 25 at a time.

What is the most elegant way to perform this in F#?

Comment: It might take me a while to digest these, I'm still wrapping my head around F#.
I wonder if the easiest way to do this in C# or F# is:
1) Concat all the emails into one big string. But every 25 emails use ;; instead of ; as the separator
2) Then do a String.Split using ;;
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to break into groups of at most N:

```
// break a sequence up into a sequence of arrays, 
// each of length at most 'n'
let Break n (s:seq<_>) =
    seq {
        use e = s.GetEnumerator()
        while e.MoveNext() do
            let i = ref 0
            yield [|
                yield e.Current
                i := !i + 1
                while !i < n && e.MoveNext() do            
                    yield e.Current
                    i := !i + 1 |] }
```

and then your solution is just something like

```
let Sendmail addr = printf "%A\n\n" addr
let allMails = [for i in 1..25 -> sprintf "a%i@example.com" i]
allMails 
|> Break 5
|> Seq.map (fun arr -> System.String.Join(";", arr))
|> Seq.iter Sendmail
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is still relevant, here is a function to join a sequence of strings using delimiter but without conversion to array.

```
open System
open System.Text

/// Join a sequence of strings using a delimiter.
/// Equivalent to String.Join() but without arrays.
let join (items : seq<string>) (delim : string) =
    // Collect the result in the string builder buffer
    // The end-sequence will be "item1,delim,...itemN,delim"
    let buff = 
        Seq.fold 
            (fun (buff :StringBuilder) (s:string) -> buff.Append(s).Append(delim)) 
            (new StringBuilder()) 
            items

    // We don't want the last delim in the result buffer, remove
    buff.Remove(buff.Length-delim.Length, delim.Length).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not overly pretty, but it works:

```
let breakWords separator groupSize (input : string) =
    let words = input.Split([| separator |])
    let arraySize = words.Length / groupSize + (if words.Length % groupSize > 0 then 1 else 0)
    let groups = Array.init arraySize (fun index ->
        let startIndex = index * groupSize
        let endIndex = Math.Min(startIndex + groupSize - 1, words.Length - 1)
        words.[startIndex .. endIndex])
    groups |> Seq.map (fun x -> String.Join(";", x))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Seq module has a windowed function, but that gives you a sliding window, so no good for this question.

Here's my version, I haven't tested how the performance compares with other answers, but it's prettier (I think!)

```
//Add an "extension function" to the Seq module
module Seq = 
    let rec chunks n (s:#seq<_>) =
        seq {
                 if Seq.length s <= n then
                    yield s
                 else
                    yield Seq.take n s
                    yield! chunks n (Seq.skip n s)           
            }

//Make curried version of String.Join
let join sep (s:#seq<string>) = System.String.Join(sep, Array.of_seq s)

//Compose the bits together
let mailMerge n = Seq.chunks n >> Seq.map (join ";")

//Test
mailList |> mailMerge 25
```

You could maybe look at [Array slices](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrsmith/archive/2008/12/09/f-zen-array-slices.aspx) too.